# ios push notification/ message without device token

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, aws-iot

I'm trying to send a push notification or a message from my IOT button to all the users who have installed my iOS and android app. Is it possible to do it, given that I don't have the user's device tokens with me?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to send push notification w/o device token. Because IOT does not recognise for which device send push notification.

Comment: Thanks. But I guess there should be some way to do it. I need to send a message or notification to the mobile device/ app. But I neither know the user's mobile number nor the device token. Can we do it using a server or database?

Comment: I dont think so it is possible, if yes than i glad to know how it will run.

Comment: This is not possible. Server needs to know device token to send out GCM/APNS notifications.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I subscribed the device tokens from my app to AWS topic and now I'm pushing messages to the topic. The same thing can be implemented on Server (instead of topics), but you can't do it without device token

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively(For Send notification without device token to everyone) You can use "Topic"

1. Make every user subscribe to topic in your android app using

FirebaseMessaging.getInstance.subscribeToTopic("")

2. Now using FCM library code send notification to those who subscribed to your topics.
   As everyone has subscribed so everybody will get notification.

Note: Code for send notification to subscribed you can google it.

This is my first answer. Hope it will help. njy coding.